# I have done this question on leetcode Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: c++, string, hashmap, substring

my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        
        if(s.length()==0){
            return 0;
        }

        
        unordered_map<char, int> map;
        int j=0,c=0,x=c,st=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(map.find(s[i])==map.end()){
                map[s[i]]++;
                x++;
                continue;
            }
            else{
                auto it1=map.find(s[j]);
                auto it2=map.find(s[i-1]);
                map.erase(it1, it2);
                j++;
                i=j-1;
                if(x>c){
                    c=x;
                    x=0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(x>c){
            c=x;
         }
        
        return c;
        
    }
};
```

and getting the following error:

```
Line 1988: Char 19: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const char, int>, false>' (hashtable.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:1997:19
```

can anyone explain me why i'm getting this error

Comment: It's caused by this line: `map.erase(it1, it2);` you need to check if the iterator is the end of map.

Comment: Offtopic: you do not need `unordered_map` use simple array and char value as an index it be way faster.

Comment: In general: Erasing entire ranges of `unordered_map`s usually is not meaningful as you do not have control over the order in which the elements are placed in, that depends entirely on the hash function in use.

Comment: Apart from fully clearing, of course...

Comment: ohk thanks to all of u for the help